# How to use geoserver/openlayer in android? How to create offline maps with geoserver/openlayers?

Tags: android, openlayers, geoserver

I would like to create offline map with geoserver in android. How to do this?

Comment: use a tile cache or OGC geopackage? what does your client require?

Comment: how to use OGC geopackage? Require is my project in university.  i have to make offline maps by geoserver và openlayers. But i don't know how to use it.

Comment: A quick hint would be that you can add `WebView` widget to your layout and place your OL/JS/HTML/CSS files into the Assets directory and reference them. There are a lot of examples on GitHub. But I don't mind about the Geoserver and actually, that's my question too :)